# Automatically selecting street segments from address list?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2, select-by-location, address, streets

I browsed around this site and a couples of other QGIS sites, and couldn't find solutions to my problems. However, I'm quite new to QGIS, so my question is possibly pretty naive.

I need to create map of a city, containing all the streets of the city (I already finished this using OpenStreetMap). Then, I have a list of addresses (around 2,000 addresses, in .csv format) that I need to locate in my city map. However, instead of geolocate them as points on the map, I need to highlight the street segments that each address belongs to. I currently face two problems:

1. how to automatically tag the streets that contains at least a location in my address list? and
2. how to select only the street segment with the location, not the entire street?

I'm using QGIS 2.18.15 on Mac.

Comment: If you've already been able to geolocate the addresses as points (if not, try GeoCoding plugin), you can use those points to do a spatial selection over the street segments layer.

Comment: Agree with @Carlos MSF, geocode them first (this will put the points near the segment), then spatial join them (by nearest feature).  Finally, you can select the segments that spatially joined successfully.